# Kubernetes external secret "cannot read secret data from Vault: Error making API request" 403

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, hashicorp-vault, external-secrets-operator

I'm trying to integrate my AKS cluster with my Hashicorp vault by following the countless examples online which all seem very straight forward. However, I can't seem to get around the 403 error on the external secret. No idea what I'm missing here.

Here are the details:

--Create token secret:

```
kubectl create secret generic vault-token --from-literal=xxx
```

--Apply secret store:

```
apiVersion: external-secrets.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterSecretStore
metadata:
  name: vault-backend
spec:
  provider:
    vault:
      server: "https://vault-public-vault-replaced.replaced.z1.hashicorp.cloud:8200"
      path: "secret"
      version: "v1"
      auth:
        tokenSecretRef:
          name: "vault-token"
          key: "token"
```

--Secret store is valid:

```
NAME            AGE   STATUS   CAPABILITIES   READY
vault-backend   72s   Valid    ReadWrite      True
```

--Manually create secret:

```
vault kv put -mount=secret secret key=secret-value                                                                             
=== Secret Path ===
secret/data/secret

======= Metadata =======
Key                Value
---                -----
created_time       2023-12-06T03:16:22.778004757Z
custom_metadata    <nil>
deletion_time      n/a
destroyed          false
version            2
```

--External secret:

```
apiVersion: external-secrets.io/v1beta1
kind: ExternalSecret
metadata:
  name: test-external-secret
spec:
  refreshInterval: "15s"
  secretStoreRef:
    name: vault-backend
    kind: ClusterSecretStore
  target:
    name: test-external-secret
    creationPolicy: Owner
  data:
    - secretKey: test-external-secret-key
      remoteRef:
        key: secret/secret
        property: key
```

--External secret status:

```
Name:         test-external-secret
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
API Version:  external-secrets.io/v1beta1
Kind:         ExternalSecret
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2023-12-06T03:19:43Z
  Generation:          1
  Managed Fields:
    API Version:  external-secrets.io/v1beta1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .:
          f:kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
      f:spec:
        .:
        f:data:
        f:refreshInterval:
        f:secretStoreRef:
          .:
          f:kind:
          f:name:
        f:target:
          .:
          f:creationPolicy:
          f:deletionPolicy:
          f:name:
    Manager:      kubectl-client-side-apply
    Operation:    Update
    Time:         2023-12-06T03:19:43Z
    API Version:  external-secrets.io/v1beta1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:status:
        .:
        f:conditions:
    Manager:         external-secrets
    Operation:       Update
    Subresource:     status
    Time:            2023-12-06T03:19:44Z
  Resource Version:  2182430
  UID:               e68cbb3f-05de-4eaf-bcf5-7cdebac52b3f
Spec:
  Data:
    Remote Ref:
      Conversion Strategy:  Default
      Decoding Strategy:    None
      Key:                  secret/secret
      Property:             key
    Secret Key:             test-external-secret-key
  Refresh Interval:         15s
  Secret Store Ref:
    Kind:  ClusterSecretStore
    Name:  vault-backend
  Target:
    Creation Policy:  Owner
    Deletion Policy:  Retain
    Name:             test-external-secret
Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2023-12-06T03:19:44Z
    Message:               could not get secret data from provider
    Reason:                SecretSyncedError
    Status:                False
    Type:                  Ready
Events:
  Type     Reason        Age                   From              Message
  ----     ------        ----                  ----              -------
  Warning  UpdateFailed  66s (x16 over 3m52s)  external-secrets  cannot read secret data from Vault: Error making API request.

URL: GET https://vault-public-vault-replaced.replaced.z1.hashicorp.cloud:8200/v1/secret/secret
Code: 403. Errors:

* 1 error occurred:
  * permission denied
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Follow these guides-
https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/tutorials/kubernetes/kubernetes-azure-aks
and https://anassolanki.medium.com/installation-and-configuration-of-hashicorp-vault-aks-bdf59a87b8db

Comment: Is there a policy authorizing reading the KV2 secret?

Comment: @Arko thanks for the reply. I'm actually using Tanzu Application Platform so I'm tied to using its external-secrets package the way it's designed. However, once that's installed, it's just a matter of creating the SecretStore and ExternalSecret objects which are not specific to Tanzu. Those guides don't appear to use those objects which is what I need to do. 

I have read/write permissions using the same token though which I've verified by running vault kv put/list commands.

Comment: @MatthewSchuchard thanks for the reply. I have very little experience using Vault, but I just created a cluster and it tells me it created the required policies for me so I'm assuming that's in place:

"Your Vault cluster was created with the KV Template, so we've set up a sample KV v2 secret and read/write policy for you."

I can't seem to find it in the UI to verify though. However, since I'm able to write keys to vault and read them using the vault kv command, I'm assuming I have all the permissions I need.